# Glimpse for ASP.NET Mystery Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, glimpse

I've installet the Glimpse NuGet package in my ASP.Ntt MVC3 web project. I'm getting errors on the web server because in my _Layout.cshtml master page there is the following reference:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Glimpse/Resource/?resource=Pager")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There is no Glimpse directory anywhere in the web project, though. So something is wrong here.

I can't find any clues in the Glimpse documentation (which is better than most). So, is that directory supposed to be there? What puts it there? Why isn't it there on my system? Should I just remove the reference from my _Layout.cshtml?

I've tried re-installing the Glimpse NuGet package but that doesn't fix things. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are getting that script tag added to your layouts file, as Glimpse does not require modifications to anything in your application except configuration.

You should be able to remove that line.

Further, let us know all of the Glimpse packages you have installed and we'll look into any misbehaving packages.

Comment: I did remove the tag and the error went away and nothing seems to be broken, so all's well that ends well I guess. I wish I knew how it got there though. Currently I have only Glimpse for Elmah installed. Perhaps the issue that Evgeniy linked to is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Actually one thing that i found using google that this is somehow linked to ELMAH logger:
https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/73

Hope that will help you or give the idea

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely (supposed to be?) handled by MVC routing. Looks like the code for Glimpse is here: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/ so dig in. :D